# JavaScript Avatar

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database, inventory

I'm trying to create a javascript avatar. E.G with Head Items, body items etc... I have a PHP script that queries the database and retrieves the current items the avatar/user is wearing, it's response is in a serialised array.
The item/avatar images are in E.G: http://blahblahblahBlah.com/graphic/itemtype/id.png

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I want to know how to achieve this. (Create an inventory system using Javascript)

Comment: Actually, I wanted to say that your question is too broad. Narrow it a little bit. Show what you have done and where you are stuck. For example if you can't load images properly, ask a question about that particular problem. From this question, it may seem that you want somebody to do it whole for you.

Answer (score 1):

If all your images are in one file, you have two choices. Firstly, you could split it into many files. But the better way would be to keep it in one file, and then make `div`s with a background image; and use an offset.

For instance, if you had a **hammer**, and it was sized **24 * 24**, located at **100, 100** you would do this. Assuming you had a file called `http://blahblahblahBlah.com/character.php`:

**CSS**:

```
.hammerPic {
   width: 24px; height: 24px;
   background-image: url('graphic/itemtype/id.png');
   background-position: -100px -100px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="hammerPic" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can load image data from text with data uris. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme, if that was your question:)