# open source jquery or html for generating avatars?

Tags: jquery, html, avatar

I've been looking for quite a while for any open source implementation of an avatar library (anything that will support basic operations, such as selecting gender, eyes, clothing etc).

Since avatars on the web are very commonly used I was surprised that I couldn't find any open source framework. I am looking for something written either in jquery or in html 5.

For an example: http://www.doppelme.com/

Thank you!

Comment: avatars are artistic. They rely on images. The rest is simple manipulation, there is little code involved.

Comment: I don't think I've explained myself correctly. I am looking for a framework that creates avatar, an avatar generation framework if you will.

Comment: @vondip just steal some images and paste them together. use MS paint, it is the best!

Comment: @Raynos LOL. You're joking, right?

Comment: @Raynos, thank you for the genuine response  :-)

Comment: @vondip @NeXxeuS Of cours it's a joke, Seriously though there's nothing around for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists no framework, but this is simple to do if you use javascript and have a library of images (eyes, hair, etc.). Then you can send the image data to PHP, using HTML5's canvas.

Another question addressing a similar issue: [JavaScript Avatar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377211/javascript-avatar)